# How to Restrict Browser

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I build a site in mvc3 , i want to restrict my site on firefox .

i mean to say that when anyone open my site on firefox it open correctly but when anyone opens it on chrome or IE it give an customze error . I am using c# with mvc3

Comment: Wouldn't it be smarter to find the root cause of the errors in IE and Chrome?

Comment: Use javascript to detect the user's browser. http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Comment: Why do you want prevent site from opening in Chrom and IE, it is totaly against user experience. IF the problem is that site does not look good in IE or Chrom, then it just should be cross-browser bugfixed

Answer (score 3):

You could write a [global action filter](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/08/15/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters.aspx) which will test the User-Agent HTTP request header:

```
public class FireFoxOnlyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var userAgent = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"];
        if (!IsFirefox(userAgent))
        {
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/Unauthorized.cshtml"
            };
        }
    }

    private bool IsFirefox(string userAgent)
    {
        // up to you to implement this method. You could use
        // regular expressions or simple IndexOf method or whatever you like
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and then register this filter in Global.asax:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new FireFoxOnlyAttribute());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the user-agent of the user connected to your website, which may be retrieved via this call in your controller:

Request.UserAgent

Not that I agree with such a pattern, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple javascript function you may add to your code and perform the actions against.

```
function detect_browser() {
    var agt=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    if (agt.indexOf("firefox") != -1) return true;
    else{
        window.location="";//Here within quotes write the location of your error page.
    }
}
```

On main page you may call the function on page load event. Though this practice is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You could test the Request.UserAgent as part of a constraint on the route.

For example, you could define a route constraint routine as follows:

```
public class UserAgentConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private string requiredUserAgent;

    public UserAgentConstraint(string agentParam)
    {
        requiredUserAgent = agentParam;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return httpContext.Request.UserAgent != null && httpContext.Request.UserAgent.Contains(requiredUserAgent);
    }
}
```

Then add the following constraint to a route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, //Parameter defaults
    new { customConstraint = new UserAgentConstraint("Firefox") } //Constraint
);
```